# Как обратиться к внутренним элементам кнопки?

Tags: c#, wpf

допустим у меня есть такой код в XAML для кнопки:

```
<Button Height="60" Width="60" Margin="655,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Button_Click" >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="controlLayout">
                        <Ellipse x:Name="buttonSurface" Fill="LightGreen"
                            StrokeThickness="2" 
                            Stroke="Gray" StrokeDashCap="Flat" />
                        <Label x:Name="buttonCaption" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Content="I"/>
                        <Border Margin="43,0,-43,0"/>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

И я хочу создать событие в котором обращаюсь к этой кнопке по имени и меняю ее цвет (в данном случае там зеленый), на пол секунды и потом цвет становится обратно зеленым. Так вот как мне обратится к внутренним элементам кнопки (через эллипс я так понимаю надо менять цвет), до кнопки могу обратиться, а вот далее возникают проблемы. Буду благодарен помощи!

Comment: Вы не должны хотеть через C# код обращаться к XAML элементам. Если это так, то вы делаете сразу что-то не то. WPF это про привязки, и XAML, хотите поменять цвет на время, привязывайте свойство и по его изменению, триггером, в XAML, запускайте анимацию смены цвета. В хорошем, грамотном WPF проекте, у вас не должно быть вообще `x:Name`, только если вы их используете в самом XAML, не более.

Comment: Не используйте в WPF `Label`, используйте `TextBlock`.